# BatchNormalization layer in Keras gives unexpected output values

Tags: tensorflow, keras, normalization, batch-normalization

Given the input values `[1, 5]` and normalizing them, should yield something like `[-1, 1]` [if I understand correctly](https://kratzert.github.io/2016/02/12/understanding-the-gradient-flow-through-the-batch-normalization-layer.html), because

```
mean = 3
var = 4
result = (x - mean) / sqrt(var)
```

However this minimal example

```
import numpy as np

import keras
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras import backend as K

shape = (1,2,1)
input = Input(shape=shape)
x = BatchNormalization(center=False)(input) # no beta
model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=x)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='sgd')

# training with dummy data
training_in = [np.random.random(size=(10, *shape))]
training_out = [np.random.random(size=(10, *shape))]
model.fit(training_in, training_out, epochs=10)

data_in = np.array([[[[1], [5]]]], dtype=np.float32)
data_out = model.predict(data_in)

print('gamma   :', K.eval(model.layers[1].gamma))
#print('beta    :', K.eval(model.layers[1].beta))
print('moving_mean:', K.eval(model.layers[1].moving_mean))
print('moving_variance:', K.eval(model.layers[1].moving_variance))

print('epsilon :', model.layers[1].epsilon)
print('data_in :', data_in)
print('data_out:', data_out)
```

produces the following output:

```
gamma   : [ 0.80644524]
moving_mean: [ 0.05885344]
moving_variance: [ 0.91000736]
epsilon : 0.001
data_in : [[[[ 1.]
   [ 5.]]]]
data_out: [[[[ 0.79519051]
   [ 4.17485714]]]]
```

So it is `[0.79519051, 4.17485714]` instead of `[-1, 1]`.

I had a look at the [source](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/60cf7ca6b28967b9ab9b41a959520532028eeaa5/keras/layers/normalization.py#L12), and the values seem to be forwarded to [tf.nn.batch_normalization](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/batch_normalization). And this [looks](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/e55574f28257bdacd744dcdba86c839e661b1b2a/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py#L755) like the result should be what I except, but obviously it is not.

So how are the output values calculated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `gamma`, the right equation is actually `result = gamma * (x - mean) / sqrt(var)` for batch normalization, *BUT* `mean` and `var` are not always the same:

- During training (fit), they are `mean_batch` and `var_batch` calculated using the input values of the batch (they are just the mean and variance of your batch)), just as you're doing. In the meanwhile, a global `moving_mean` and `moving_variance` are learnt this way: `moving_mean = alpha * moving_mean + (1-alpha) * mean_batch`, with alpha is a kind of learning rate, in (0,1), usually above 0.9. `moving_mean` and `moving_variance`are approximations of the real mean and variance of all your *training* data. `Gamma` is also learnt, by usual gradient descent, to best fit your output.
- During inference (predict), you just use the learnt values of `moving_mean` and `moving_variance`, not at all `mean_batch` and `var_batch`. You also use the learnt `gamma`.

So `0.05885344` is just an approximation of the mean of your random input data, `0.91000736` of its variance, and you're using these to normalize your new data [1, 5]. You can easily chack check that `[0.79519051, 4.17485714]=gamma * ([1, 5] - moving_mean)/sqrt(moving_var)`

edit: `alpha` is called momentum in keras, if you want to check it.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot. Could you also tell me where beta fits into the formula when `center=True`? My guess whould have been `output = gamma * (input - moving_mean) / sqrt(moving_variance) + beta` but when I [enable center](https://ideone.com/TNRlFH) the [output](https://ideone.com/d3rROd) does not match.

Comment: It should be as you say according to tensorflow, given [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/batch_normalization). [Keras](https://keras.io/layers/normalization/) looks like it may do `output = gamma * ((input - moving_mean) / sqrt(moving_variance) + beta)`instead in their doc. However none fits exactly, I dont know why...

Comment: I found the issue. We were not using epsilon. The fully correct formula is `result = gamma * (input - moving_mean) / sqrt(moving_variance + epsilon) + beta`.

Comment: I tried with that and did not get the right error .. Maybe I just miscopied the numbers or sthg...

Answer (score 0):

The correct formula is this:

```
result = gamma * (input - moving_mean) / sqrt(moving_variance + epsilon) + beta
```

And here a script for verification:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K

from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization

np.random.seed(0)

print('=== keras model ===')
input_shape = (1,2,1)
input = Input(shape=input_shape)
x = BatchNormalization()(input)
model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=x)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='sgd')
training_in = [np.random.random(size=(10, *input_shape))]
training_out = [np.random.random(size=(10, *input_shape))]
model.fit(training_in, training_out, epochs=100, verbose=0)
data_in = [[[1.0], [5.0]]]
data_model = np.array([data_in])
result = model.predict(data_model)
gamma = K.eval(model.layers[1].gamma)
beta = K.eval(model.layers[1].beta)
moving_mean = K.eval(model.layers[1].moving_mean)
moving_variance = K.eval(model.layers[1].moving_variance)
epsilon = model.layers[1].epsilon
print('gamma:          ', gamma)
print('beta:           ', beta)
print('moving_mean:    ', moving_mean)
print('moving_variance:', moving_variance)
print('epsilon:        ', epsilon)
print('data_in:        ', data_in)
print('result:         ', result)

print('=== numpy ===')
np_data = [data_in[0][0][0], data_in[0][1][0]]
np_mean = moving_mean[0]
np_variance = moving_variance[0]
np_offset = beta[0]
np_scale = gamma[0]
np_result = [np_scale * (x - np_mean) / math.sqrt(np_variance + epsilon) + np_offset for x in np_data]
print(np_result)

print('=== tensorflow ===')
tf_data = tf.constant(data_in)
tf_mean = tf.constant(moving_mean)
tf_variance = tf.constant(moving_variance)
tf_offset = tf.constant(beta)
tf_scale = tf.constant(gamma)
tf_variance_epsilon = epsilon
tf_result = tf.nn.batch_normalization(tf_data, tf_mean, tf_variance, tf_offset, tf_scale, tf_variance_epsilon)
tf_sess = tf.Session()
print(tf_sess.run(tf_result))

print('=== keras backend ===')
k_data = K.constant(data_in)
k_mean = K.constant(moving_mean)
k_variance = K.constant(moving_variance)
k_offset = K.constant(beta)
k_scale = K.constant(gamma)
k_variance_epsilon = epsilon
k_result = K.batch_normalization(k_data, k_mean, k_variance, k_offset, k_scale, k_variance_epsilon)
print(K.eval(k_result))
```

Output:

```
gamma:           [ 0.22297101]
beta:            [ 0.49253803]
moving_mean:     [ 0.36868709]
moving_variance: [ 0.41429576]
epsilon:         0.001
data_in:         [[[1.0], [5.0]]]
result:          [[[[ 0.71096909]
   [ 2.09494853]]]]

=== numpy ===
[0.71096905498374263, 2.0949484904433255]

=== tensorflow ===
[[[ 0.71096909]
  [ 2.09494853]]]

=== keras backend ===
[[[ 0.71096909]
  [ 2.09494853]]]
```